# What are the performance impacts of using DecimalFormat with ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading, decimalformat

I have an implementation which uses `DecimalFormat`(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) API.

*Solution1*: The argument is because `DecimalFormat` is **NOT** thread-safe, I am inclined to use `ThreadLocal` for `DecimalFormat` creation to make it thread safe. Also, it will save creation of DecimalFormat object for each invocation

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> restrictTo1DecimalPlace =
            ThreadLocal.withInitial
                    (() -> new DecimalFormat("0.0%", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

*Solution 2*: Another simple solution is to give away object reusability and create object of `DecimalFormat` everytime.

```
new DecimalFormat("0.0%", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)).format(decimalValueToFormat)
```

What is better?

Comment: Unless you can prove the second one causes a real performance problem, which is very unlikely, keep it simple and create a new one when you need it.

Comment: Create new instances. If you prove that is slow for your use case, consider using ThreadLocal. The complexity of ThreadLocal is that you have to ensure you clean the ThreadLocal when a thread is destroyed, otherwise you can cause memory leaks.

Comment: @Augusto Failure to clean up is not aproblem if the thread is destroyed, it's a problem when it's a thread in a pool, that is reused for other tasks. The associated ThreadLocal content can not be garbage collected, yet it's also no longer used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most applications, the difference will not matter, so you'll want the simpler option.

You can verify this by benchmarking both alternatives:

```
public abstract class Benchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> restrictTo1DecimalPlace =
                ThreadLocal.withInitial
                        (() -> new DecimalFormat("0.0%", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)));            
        Benchmark[] marks = {
            new Benchmark("ThreadLocal") {
                @Override
                protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                        sb.append(restrictTo1DecimalPlace.get().format(i * 0.01));
                    }
                    return sb;
                };
            },
            new Benchmark("new Format") {
                @Override
                protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                        sb.append(new DecimalFormat("0.0%", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)).format(i * 0.01));
                    }
                    return sb;
                };
            },
        };
        for (Benchmark mark : marks) {
            System.out.println(mark);
        }
    }

    final String name;

    public Benchmark(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + time() + " ns / iteration";
    }

    private BigDecimal time() {
        try {
            // automatically detect a reasonable iteration count (and trigger just in time compilation of the code under test)
            int iterations;
            long duration = 0;
            for (iterations = 1; iterations < 1_000_000_000 && duration < 1_000_000_000; iterations *= 2) {
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                run(iterations);
                duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
            }
            return new BigDecimal((duration) * 1000 / iterations).movePointLeft(3);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the code under test.
     * @param iterations
     *            number of iterations to perform
     * @return any value that requires the entire code to be executed (to
     *         prevent dead code elimination by the just in time compiler)
     * @throws Throwable
     *             if the test could not complete successfully
     */
    protected abstract Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable;
}
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
ThreadLocal 260.132 ns / iteration
new Format  363.199 ns / iteration
```

So the difference between getting the format from a ThreadLocal or creating a new one was about 0.0000001 seconds. Unless your application formats millions of strings every second, this is not worth thinking about :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is a significant difference

> In recent times, JVM performance has been multiplied manifold and so object creation is no longer considered as expensive as it was done earlier.

But it's true that the Allocation of new DecimalFormat has memory impact that may also consume time.
It's very reasonable to create new instances, and that's how java code is supposed to work.

One thing you can try is to pre-allocate DecimalFormat instances and keep them in a simple [object pool](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-object-pool-java).

Comment: Even if create a pool, I am back to square one i.e. as DecimalFormat is not thread safe which means a left state  in DecimalFormat could leave further implications

Comment: when you borrow from the pool your object is only used by one thread.

Comment: Than each new thread will create new object which I wanted to avoid in first place.

Comment: The thread borrows an instance that was previously created (i.e in your application start time).

Comment: if that object application created during startup is used, than what happens to that object? Is it destroyed? if it is destroyed after use than each thread will create a new object everytime which is why I wanted to save it if possible. if its not destroyed, then how do you ensure that state in DecimalFormat will not impact future invocations?

Comment: The concept is not to destroy it. you just  reset the object(i.e set it to 0) and return it to the pool.  but again I wonder if the creation is that expensive that you'll get enough performance boost. allocation should happen fast

Comment: _you just reset the object(i.e set it to 0)_ how can we do it? that will be great.